# Wordpress tags as twitter sharer URL hastags

Tags: tags, twitter

I want to share a wordpress post on twitter. I'm using this :

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share?url=<?php the_permalink() ?>&text=<?php the_title() ?>&via=<?php the_author() ?>&hashtags=<?php the_tags('', '') ?>" ></a>
```

My problem is that `the_tags()` prints the tags inside the `<a>` tag. How can I use `the_tags('', '')` ( which separates the tags with comma as the hashtag needs to be ) for twitter hashtags ?

I would appreciate any solutions without the use of a plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`get_the_tags()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_tags) with a little bit of processing will do it:

```
$tags = get_the_tags();
$tag_list = wp_list_pluck($tags,'name');
$tag_list = implode(',',$tag_list);
var_dump($tag_list);
```

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pluck

Comment: then I should put <? echo $tags ?> in the URL ?

Comment: `echo $tag_list;` actually, but yes.

Comment: very nice thanks. it worked. but there is a problem that the php codes prints this : string 'Elearnica' (length=9) ( Elearnica is the post tag ) how can I stop printing it ?

Comment: The `var_dump()` is for debugging only. Remove it from your working code.